# Problem with installation of HANDBRAKE 0.10.5

Tags: 14.04, xfce, handbrake

I want to install version 0.10.5 of HANDBRAKE but I don't know how.

I tried this method :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install handbrake=0.10.5-zhb-1ppa1~wily1
```

But I got an error that the version does not exist

I also tried this method :

1. Download `.deb` file from Launchpad -> Handbrake 0.10.5 (Ubuntu 64bit)
2. Copy the `.deb` file to `/var/cache/apt/archives` folder
3. Run `sudo apt-get install handbrake=0.10.5`

But I got the same error as the error above

Can you help me please ?

I'm using Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS with xfce

Comment: Please make point 4 clearer. Also, specify whether it is Ubuntu 14.4 or 14.10.

Comment: you can ignore point 4 , it just if point 3 was succeeded (but i doesn't)
,And i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with xfce

Comment: Use the command `sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk`, assuming that you have not removed the repositoy.

Comment: But i think it will install me the new version (1.01) , I want the old version 0.10.5